# Titled border issue for JPanel

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-6.9

I developed an application using netbeans. But the title of the titled border of JPanel has some alignment issue. In the 'show preview' the title is displaying as expected, but while running the code, the title goes up above the panel. Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

## Expected panel

[image]

## Actual panel while running the project

[image]

## Panel properties

[image]

I know this is some property issue with panel. I googled by couldn't find a valid solution. Stack experts please help to resolve this issue. I am using netbeans 7.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Netbeans look and feel:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBLookAndFeels

Default is set to Nimbus, you probably want Windows.

Answer (score 1):

By editing Look and feel setting of the application you can get the expected result.

```
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
```

You have to change nimbus look and feel to windows..

```
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below option

```
jPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE), "Sample title", TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, TitledBorder.CENTER, new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12), Color.BLUE))
```