# Titled Border Java Form

Tags: java, netbeans

First, i see the same problem here, but nobody answers:

[Titled border issue for JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994569/titled-border-issue-for-jpanel)

In the "show preview" the title is displaying of the Panel border as expected, but while running the code, the title goes up above the panel. Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

**Preview design:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6miFx.jpg

**Running design**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEMoL.jpg

I use Netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: Seems like a look & feel problem.

Comment: How change to the same of preview design?

Comment: It's a look and feel issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16160872/5969411

Comment: I guess you could argue it's also a problem with the Netbeans preview, not that I use swing previews or know how to fix it.

Comment: Exactly, the problem is that Netbeans preview design look diferent to running.

Answer (score 1):

I found a list of borders [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).
I think you want this one (modified slightly from the aforementioned source).

```
Border loweredetched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED);

//Titled borders
TitledBorder title;
title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                   loweredetched, "title");
title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.LEFT);
jComp10.setBorder(title);
```